# Parse javascript date

Tags: javascript, json

I have JSON response that has date value as below

> `/Date(1494468000000)/`

How can I parse this to Date object without using any library?

Comment: is that a string?

Comment: Is the JSON something like `{"date": "/Date(1494468000000)/"}`?

Comment: @D-reaper yes, string

Comment: @felipeptcho yes

Comment: I would just get the number somehow and pass it to javascript Date built in object.

Comment: @D-reaper, yes can use regex but that'd be inefficient because there's many objects.

Comment: @D-reaper: This isn't a chatroom.

Comment: Ain't rocket science `+str.replace(/\D/g,'')`